# Push alsa capture volume over limit on USB headset

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, alsa

I want to push capture volume on my RPi3 with ALSA of my USB headset (microphone) over the limit that is, in my case, 6 dB.
I tried every example i've found and the only reasonable way seems to be to create a preamplified channel with `softvol` plugin.

So i tried every configuration file i've found but i could not get it working. I cannot see any new channel on alsamixer.

The `asound.conf` file i'm using now is this:

```
pcm.!default {
  #Tried using both "plug" and "hw"
  type plug
  slave.pcm "softvol"
  slave.channels 1
}

pcm.softvol {
  type softvol
  slave {
    #Tried using "dmix" and "hw:1,0"
    #pcm "dmix"
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }

  # Add a control slider in your mixer interfaces
  control {
    name "PreAmp"
    card 1
    # i.e. card 0 or card 2
  }

  # Minimum dB when slider is at 0%
  min_dB -6.0

  # Maximum DB when slider is at 100%
  max_dB 32.0

  # How many levels the slider should go through
  # i.e. how granular do you want your control to be
  resolution 6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)?
you could do something like

`rec -r 44100 - test.wav gain 6`

but it amplify your signal last in the chain, as a effect, not sure how to amplify your main insert at the beginning, but still... same result

[see here how to select sox record device for raspberry](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39480&p=345955)

Comment: I forgot to explain that i need to amplify at the source because i don't want to record but i need to stream the audio capture.

Comment: You also can do this with sox, [here how](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-radio-station-with-raspberry-pi/). And you stream the amplify signal, not dry one.

Comment: I guess that increasing the volume with `sox` is no different than increasing it with `softvol`.